# Is there a Riemannian submersion from $Gl(2,\mathbb{R})$ to the Poincare half plane?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the Poincare half plane with the hyperbolic metric.  Let $Gl(2,\mathbb{R})$ be equipped with a left invariant metric?

> Is there a Riemannian submersion from $Gl(2,\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{H}$? If yes, what is a precise formula for such a Riemannian submersion?

Comment: Have you tried considering  the natural  maps $GL(2,\mathbb{R})\to SL(2,\mathbb{R})\to SL(2,\mathbb{R})/SO(2,\mathbb{R})\sim \mathbb{H}^2$ and see if the metric on $\mathbb{H}^2$ comes from something interesting ?

Comment: This at least gives a submersion, the remaining question is wether it is a Riemannien submersion for some metric of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @Thomas  Thank you for your comment. What do you mean by the quotiont in your first comment?Further more what is the map in the first arrows, is it the Grahm Schmitd map? If yes is not the range (SO2)?

Comment: The first map is just the the map $M\mapsto \tfrac{1}{|\det(M)|}M$. Maybe the map $f:SL(2,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{H}^2$ is easier to see, consider the action $(A,p)\mapsto A\cdot p$ of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ by isometries on $\mathbb{H}^2$. $f$ is then $A\mapsto A\cdot p_0$ where $p_0$ is some reference point. The isotropy group of $p_0$ is then some copy of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ inside $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: (The first arrow should be $M\mapsto \frac{1}{|\det M|^{1/2}}M$ and it works only on $GL(2,\mathbb{R})^+$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the hyperbolic metric $g$ on $\mathbb{H}^2$ by 
$$
g = \frac{1}{2y^2} (d x^2 + d y^2).
$$
The Iwasawa decomposition yields an isomorpism $SL(2)/SO(2)=\mathbb{H}^2$ which is given by
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}} \mapsto \frac{1}{(a_{21}^2 + a_{22}^2)}(a_{11} a_{21} + a_{12} a_{22}, 1).
$$
Moreover, if you define a metric $h$ on $SL(2)$ by 
$$
h_A (V, W) = Tr(A^{-1} V  A^{-1} W),
$$
then the projection $SL(2) \to \mathbb{H}^2$ is a Riemannian submersion. Some time ago, I've written [some notes on this](https://share.cocalc.com/share/f26774ef-f5c4-4e05-9fd3-a235d176f341/SLmodSOtoPlaneAndSym.sagews?viewer=share) (and related things concerning the Poincare upper half plane). They are not in a very good shape but may be helpful nonetheless (they were meant as a first experiment with sage).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I read it to understand its detail.

Comment: Is it really an inner product?$h_A$?may be you mean $W^{tr}?in this case why the form is symmetric?

Comment: $h_A$ is the left translation of the Killing form of $\mathfrak{sl}$ (up to some constant). Since $\mathfrak{sl}$ is semisimple, the Killing form is non-degenerate.